# XML prolog and HTML5 docytype

Tags: xml, html

Is there any reason why someone would need an XML prolog in an HTML5 document? I'm not talking about XHTML5. I'm just talking about a regular run-of-the-mill HTML page that uses the HTML5 docytpe.

Would there be any reason to have to include an XML prolog at the top of such a document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML prolog (specifically the XML declaration) indicates that a document is XML.  If the page is **not** well-formed XML, then you should definitely **not** include it.

However, data is good...  The browsers I tested this on (Firefox and Chrome in Ubuntu) had no visible problems with an XML declaration at the top of an HTML 5 page, even though the page was **not** well-formed XML.  The reason, of course, is that the HTTP server continued to serve the pages with the `text/html` content type.

Even though my small test didn't reveal errors, I can't think of any reason why this would be a good practice.  If the page is HTML5, then it may not be XML, and should not be indicated as such.  Browsers may not have a problem with this, but other tools, which look at the declaration instead of the content type, might make other assumptions.